# Splitting a dataframe based on position in python based on delimeter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df=
users|userids
user1|1
user3|3
user1,user2|1,2
user3,user4|3,4
user1,user3|1,3
user5,user6,user2|5,6,2
user11,user12,user13,user14,user15|11,12,13,14,15
```

Now I want the dataframe to be split as follows:

```
df_modified=
user|userid
user1|1
user2|2
user3|3
user4|4
user5|5
user6|6
user11|11
user12|12
user13|13
user14|14
user15|15
```

I have tried

```
df_modified=df.pivot(columns='users',values='userids')
```

Doesn't work.Actually the values in df are of type strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `.str.split` to split the strings in columns around the delimiter `,` then use `np.hstack` to stack the splitted strings in columns horizontally, finally create new dataframe from these stacked columns:

```
df_mod = pd.DataFrame({'users': np.hstack(df['users'].str.split(',')),
                       'userids': np.hstack(df['userids'].str.split(','))})\
           .drop_duplicates('users', ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
     users userids
0    user1       1
1    user2       2
2    user3       3
3    user4       4
4    user5       5
5    user6       6
6   user11      11
7   user12      12
8   user13      13
9   user14      14
10  user15      15
```

Comment: following error is encountered :ValueError: arrays must all be same length.Edited the question for a better idea.I also have elements in df which doesn't need a split

Comment: @Sam I think this should work fine even on the sample data provided in the edited question...Can you please recheck the solution on the given sample data?

Comment: I need to remove drop_duplicates for some reason it is showing an error.It works now @Shubham

Comment: @Sam happy coding!